# How do I recover my sites after uninstall MAMP?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, localhost, mamp

I'm using MAMP to work with wordpress locally, but I had some troubles with MySQL Server that wasn't starting, so I decided to uninstall MAMP.

Now that I reinstalled, MySQL Server is working but I lost everything that I've done with my sites, before I uninstall I made a backup of the entire MAMP folder.

Is there any way to recover my site from the backup?

mysql_error_log.err:

```
2019-01-20T19:17:07.354392Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-01-20T19:17:07.354481Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2019-01-20T19:17:07.355021Z 0 [ERROR] Cannot open Windows EventLog; check privileges, or start server with --log_syslog=0
2019-01-20T19:17:07.355045Z 0 [Note] C:\MAMP\\bin\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.7.24-log) starting as process 12444 ...
2019-01-20T19:19:42.728216Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-01-20T19:19:42.728309Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2019-01-20T19:19:42.728909Z 0 [ERROR] Cannot open Windows EventLog; check privileges, or start server with --log_syslog=0
2019-01-20T19:19:42.728934Z 0 [Note] C:\MAMP\\bin\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.7.24-log) starting as process 4224 ...
2019-01-20T19:21:28.706864Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-01-20T19:21:28.706960Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2019-01-20T19:21:28.707537Z 0 [ERROR] Cannot open Windows EventLog; check privileges, or start server with --log_syslog=0
2019-01-20T19:21:28.707565Z 0 [Note] C:\MAMP\\bin\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.7.24-log) starting as process 5944 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just restore/copy your database files from your backup.

On Windows, MAMP database data is located in **C:\MAMP\db\mysql**

On Mac, in **/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57**

Hope this will help you. Waiting for your feedback.

Comment: I replaced the original folder with the backup, but the mysql server did not work again

Comment: I recommend you to copy/paste error logs from /Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err into your Question. With this information it will be more clear where is the problem.

Comment: Since the error seems to be related to privileges/permissions, have you tried to "run as administrator"?

Comment: Yes and the problem continues. This problem started when my computer shut down and when I started over it stop working